# Kubernetes does not evict a pod event if it is in a "failed" state, e.g. CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a pod that had a `Pod Disruption Budget` that says at least one has to be running. While it generally works very well it leads to a peculiar problem.

I have this pod sometimes in a failed state (due to some development) so I have two pods, scheduled for two different nodes, both in a `CrashLoopBackOff` state.

Now if I want to run a `drain` or k8s version upgrade, what happens is that pod cannot ever be evicted since it knows that there should be at least one running, which will never happen.

So k8s does not evict a pod due to `Pod Disruption Budget` even if the pod is not running. Is there a way to do something with this? I think ideally k8s should treat failed pods as candidates for eviction regardless of the budget (as deleting a failing pod cannot "break" anything anyway)

Answer (score 3):

> ...if I want to run a drain or k8s version upgrade, what happens is that pod cannot ever be evicted since it knows that there should be at least one running...

`kubectl drain --disable-eviction <node>` will delete pod that is protected by PDB. Since you are fully aware of the downtime, you can first delete the PDB in question *before* draining the node.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, deleting the pod does indeed help. But if this happens automatically by upgrading the version of k8s via terraform, it is not quite obvious what is going on (i.e. there is something blocking the node drain).

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue too during k8s upgrade. Fyi, as mentioned in the other answer, `kubectl drain --disable-eviction <node>` may cause service downtime, and deleting pods might not work always when deleted pods are immediately recreated by the deployment managing the pods. Also, even if the pods are deleted successfully, it may cause service downtime depending on `PodDisruptionBudget`.

Instead, I increased the number of replicas of the pods in the deployment to honor [`PodDisruptionBudget.minAvailable` or `PodDisruptionBudget.maxUnavailable`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/#rounding-logic-when-specifying-percentages) and was able to successfully upgrade k8s while honoring `PodDisruptionBudget`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I cannot see though how will that help in the situations when all the pods of a deployment are down already?